# Copy the same model multiple times in keras

Tags: python, keras, models

I'm working in a model that contains 5 sub-models which are identical and their only difference is on their weights.

I trained each of them separately but now that I have to use them together I build the 5 of them and I get the message

> RuntimeError: The name "predictions" is used 5 times in the model. All
>   layer names should be unique.

I would like to know if there is a way to change the names of the layers inside my model without using the `name` property because there are more than 100 layers and I cannot do it manually. And if I change the name I would also like to know how to load the weights, because they are saved with the previous layer names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reached an easy solution, I'm just changing the name of the layers with:

```
model1 = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
    model1.load_weights('model1_weights.h5', by_name=True)

for i, layer in enumerate(model1.layers):
        layer.name = 'layer'+str(i)+'_model1'
```

And I did the same with the rest

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will not work when trying to rename the layers in tensorflow.keras. As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550182/keras-rename-model-and-layers), `layer.name` cannot be overriden, and `layer._name` should be used instead.

If you're working with tensorflow, try adapting the last part of @jfk's answer to:

```
for i, layer in enumerate(model1.layers):
        layer._name = 'layer'+str(i)+'_model1'
```

Comment: Working on version 2.4.1 of Tensorflow