# Keras rename model and layers

Tags: python, keras

1) I try to rename a model and the layers in Keras with TF backend, since I am using multiple models in one script.
Class Model seem to have the property model.name, but when changing it I get "AttributeError: can't set attribute".
What is the Problem here?

2) Additionally, I am using sequential API and I want to give a name to layers, which seems to be possibile with Functional API, but I found no solution for sequential API. Does anonye know how to do it for sequential API?

UPDATE TO 2): Naming the layers works, although it seems to be not documented. Just add the argument name, e.g. model.add(Dense(...,...,name="hiddenLayer1"). *Watch out, Layers with same name share weights!*

Comment: here a detailed answer to change model name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728083/change-the-model-name-given-automatically-by-keras-in-model-summary-output/62728323#62728323

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> > > **Doesn't work any more as per tf2+**

Your first problem about the model name is not reproducible on my machine.
I can set it like this. many a times these errors are caused by software versions.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(....)))
model.name="NAME"
```

As far as naming the layers, you can do it in Sequential model like this

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(...),name="NAME"))
```

> > Latest solution

use `_name`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As already said in the update, I found the solution for the layer. But the model.name is still not working. Thank you though, I assume your anwser is correct!

Comment: `model.name` uses a property decorater and can't be overriden.
The attribute `model._name` however can.

Answer (score 47):

For changing names of model.layers with tf.keras you can use the following lines:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer._name = layer.name + str("_2")
```

I needed this in a two-input model case and ran into the "AttributeError: can't set attribute", too. The thing is that there is an underlying hidden attribute _name, which causes the conflict.

Comment: Thank you.. I used `._name` instead of `.name` and it works.

Comment: Still works in tf.keras with TF 2.3. While this can be done with RNN Cells as well, be aware that Bidrectional Layers and some other things might get slightly buggy if the suffix of the original name is removed (the int counting the layer number, e.g. rnn_layer_3).

Comment: Even if it works now: This is not a public API and this could fail silently if a developer changes the underlying implementation. Moreover, the names of the layer weights are not renamed which can cause conflicts when saving the model after training.

Comment: this doesn't work in TF '2.3.2'

This is because Keras serializes the network by traversing layer._inbound_nodes and comparing against model._network_nodes; when setting layer._name, latter persists original names.

See here for the solution how to change the model network nodes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414614/2864867

Comment: Be careful using this approach, this may harm model.save() method. I got to use model.save_weights() as a workaround

Answer (score 13):

To rename a keras model in TF2.2.0:

`model._name = "newname"`

I have no idea if this is a bad idea - they don't seem to want you to do it, but it does work. To confirm, call `model.summary()` and you should see the new name.

Answer (score 11):

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49550620/8450529)  from user239457 only works with [Standard keras](https://keras.io/).

If you want to use the [Tensorflow Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras), you can do it like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential(name='Name')
model.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(5, 1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to cover all the options, regarding the title of the question, if you are using the Keras functional API you can define the model and the layers name by:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(value, value))

output_layer = Dense(2, activation = 'softmax', name = 'training_output')(dropout_new_training_layer)

model = Model(inputs= inputs, outputs=output_layer, name="my_model")
```

Answer (score 4):

To change only one layer name in a model you can use  the following lines:

```
my_model.layers[0]._name = 'my_new_name_for_the_first_layer'
my_model.layers[1]._name = 'my_new_name_for_the_second_layer'
my_model.layers[-1]._name = 'my_new_name_for_the_last_layer'
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the layer name of a **pre-trained model** on Tensorflow Keras, the solution is a bit more complex. A simple
`layer.name = "new_name"` or `layer._name = "new_name"` as proposed by other answers will not work.

[This blog post](https://nrasadi.medium.com/change-model-layer-name-in-tensorflow-keras-58771dd6bf1b) offers a solution that works for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed answer is here [How to rename Pre-Trained model ? ValueError 'Trained Model' is not a valid scope name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786982/how-to-rename-pre-trained-model-valueerror-trained-model-is-not-a-valid-scop)

We can use `model.name = "Model_Name"` when are developing model and making it ready to train. We can also give name to layers. Ex:

```
model = Sequential()
model.name = "My_Model" #Naming model
model.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(...),name="Name") #Naming layer
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the author, simply changing the name of a custom layer is not enough if you wish to use said layer multiple times. Here is a temporary but very viable solution of mine. Please feel free to copy/paste:

```
def name_custom_activation(activation):
    """ Currently, the Tensorflow library does not provide auto
        incrementation for custom layer names. Tensorflow Graphs
        requires each layer to have a unique name. Manually 
        incrementing layer names is annoying. The following trick 
        is the best method to change a layer name. It is especially 
        useful when using tf.keras.utils.plot_model to look at 
        synergistic activation models.
    """

    class_name = tf.keras.layers.Activation.__name__
    tf.keras.layers.Activation.__name__ = f'Activation_{activation.__name__}'
    activation_layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation)
    tf.keras.layers.Activation.__name__ = class_name
    return activation_layer
```

When plotting your model's graph, it looks like this:

```
def my_custom_activation(x): 
    return ... # Create your own activation function.

def create_model():
    return ... # Add your own model, which uses your custom activation.

model = create_model()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

[image: Example of the tf.keras.utils.plot_model displaying the custom name as desired.]

Answer (score -4):

for 1), I think you may build another model with right name and same structure with the exist one. then set weights from layers of the exist model to layers of the new model.