# How to rename the layers of a Keras model without corrupting the structure?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

For [some library functionality](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep/pull/239) I'm trying to rename the layers (including the input layers) of a given model.

The following minimal example shows the error I run into with my current approach (using TensorFlow 2.3):

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("model.h5")
for layer in model.layers:
    layer._name = layer.name + "_renamed"

model.to_json()
```

```
ValueError: The target structure is of type `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`
  Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 4), dtype=float32)
However the input structure is a sequence (<class 'list'>) of length 0.
```

The `model.h5` file might have been created like this, for example:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(4,))
x = Dense(5, activation='relu', name='a')(inputs)
x = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='b')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam')
model.save("model.h5")
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: In the meantime, I've solved my original problem in a different way, i.e., without renaming any layers, but it's interesting to know how one would need to approach the renaming strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**: Keras serializes the network by traversing `layer._inbound_nodes` and [comparing against](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.3/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py#L1263) `model._network_nodes`; when setting `layer._name`, latter persists *original* names.

---

**Solution**: rename `_network_nodes` accordingly. Working function at bottom, with example below:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

ipt = Input((16,))
out = Dense(16)(ipt)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')

rename(model, model.layers[1], 'new_name')
model.save('model.h5')
loaded = load_model('model.h5')
```

---

**Note**: `layer.name` is a [`@property`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.3/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1219) without a `.setter`, meaning it's not meant to be set (as evident). Further, [`layer.__setattr__`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.3/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L2756) is overridden, and performs steps in addition to setting an attribute - likely necessary, but can't be sure exactly what other effects it may have. I've included an alternative which bypasses these. Treat this as a temporary solution at best; I suggest opening an Issue on Github, as API-side changes are due.

---

**Function**:

Not foolproof - `_get_node_suffix`'s naming logic needs work (e.g. `dense_1` can confound with `dense_11`).

```py
def rename(model, layer, new_name):
    def _get_node_suffix(name):
        for old_name in old_nodes:
            if old_name.startswith(name):
                return old_name[len(name):]

    old_name = layer.name
    old_nodes = list(model._network_nodes)
    new_nodes = []

    for l in model.layers:
        if l.name == old_name:
            l._name = new_name
            # vars(l).__setitem__('_name', new)  # bypasses .__setattr__
            new_nodes.append(new_name + _get_node_suffix(old_name))
        else:
            new_nodes.append(l.name + _get_node_suffix(l.name))
    model._network_nodes = set(new_nodes)
```

Comment: So the problem here is that we can't rename the layers before compiling a model?