# How to combine two predefined models in Keras TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to build a neural network that has two inputs and uses EfficientNetB1 to extract features and fine-tune on new layers, so I wrote this code:

```
def createNet(self,shape):
    FE1 = K.applications.EfficientNetB1(include_top=False, input_shape=shape)
    FE2 = K.applications.EfficientNetB1(include_top=False, input_shape=shape)
    inp1 = FE1.input
    out1 = FE1.layers[-1].output
    inp2 = FE2.input
    out2 = FE2.layers[-1].output

    merged_out = K.layers.concatenate((out1, out2))
    # .... other layers
    self.model = K.models.Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=[merged_out])
    
    self.model.summary()
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: The name "stem_conv_pad" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.
```

So how can I build my model?

Comment: It seems like there is a layer naming conflict, because you used the same predefined model twice, so each of them has the same layers with the same names. It is possible to rename all layers in a mode, ie. see here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40886

Answer (score 1):

Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550182/keras-rename-model-and-layers) I added below codes to solve it.

```
for layer in FE2.layers:
    layer._name = layer.name + str("_2")
```